# Facing Issue in Reversing string in C without inbuilt libraries

Tags: c

I'm facing an issue in reversing a string in C without using inbuilt functions: I'm using the C89/C90 version of C on Sublime Text 3, and I'm just getting the numbers of character in my code output, but it is not showing me the reversed string.

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int size_string(char a[]){

    int count;

    for(count=0;a[count]!='\0';count++);

        return count;

}
void reverse(char *p,int size){

    int i;char temp;

    for(i=0;i<size/2;i++){

        temp=*(p+i);

        *(p+i)=*(p+size-i);     

        *(p+size-i)=temp;
    }
}
int main(){

    char a[45];int size;

    printf("Enter a string :  ");

    fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin);

    size=size_string(a);

    printf("%d\n",size);

    reverse(a,size);

    printf("%s",a);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this warning:

```
NumPyramid.c: In function 'size_string':

NumPyramid.c:4:2: warning: this 'for' clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]

    4 |  for(count=0;a[count]!='\0';count++);

      |  ^~~
NumPyramid.c:5:3: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the 'for'
    5 |   return count;

      |   ^~~~~~
```

Comment: **Protip:** `for(count=0;a[count]!='\0';count++);` >> `while(a[count++]);`

Comment: That's not an error. It's a warning. And it's right. You need to de-indent that `return` statement so it doesn't look falsely like it's related to the `for`.

Comment: @Mat No.  That's an empty loop for getting the length of the string.

Comment: `fgets()` reads the `<ENTER>` ... you may want to avoid reversing it. And print a final newline before terminating your program `printf("%s\n", a);` (or, alternatively `fflush(stdout);`) to bypass any **issues with eventual output buffering**.

Comment: See the problem with asking your real question last? Most people here missed it, so just saw the warning and closed assuming (wrongly) caused by a typo. I have edited to move it to the top. The warning needs fixing but in this case is kind of a red herring.

Answer (score 4):

#### The String

Note that you are also reversing the `NUL` byte, placing it at the beginning of the string. This causes `printf1` to terminate on the first character (`NUL`).

Try using `i+1` when counting bytes from the end of the string:

```
for(i=0;i<size/2;i++){
    temp=*(p+i);
    *(p+i)=*(p+size-(i+1));     
    *(p+size-(i+1))=temp;
}
```

---

#### The Warning:

The compiler is **warning** you about a misleading indentation after the `for` loop.

These lines:

```
for(count=0;a[count]!='\0';count++);
    return count;
```

Are misleadingly similar to (note the `;`):

```
for(count=0;a[count]!='\0';count++)
    return count;
```

But both lines behave very differently! One version returns once the loop completes, the other version returns from inside the loop.

This is a styling concern that may cause bugs to hide in plain sight.

A better formatting would be (note the indentation and the `;` in a separate line):

```
for(count=0;a[count]!='\0';count++)
    ;
return count;
```

Hence, the warning. The compiler is warning you to make sure you see this line and that you indeed wrote what you meant to write.

Answer (score 2):

change

```c
reverse(a,size);
```

to

```c
reverse(a,size-1);
```

basically your reversed string starts with a null byte that's why it doesn't print anything.

Comment: I didn't imply that it returned 3, I'm saying that OP is swapping the first char with the null byte

Comment: I upvoted your solution, but the answer would have been better with some explanation. In addition, the solution solves the fact that the `reverse` has a bug (it reverses the NUL byte)... but it would be better to fix the bug in `reverse` so the function arguments aren't misleading.

Comment: Thanks  im new on stackoverflow and in programming too so its a little mistake.Thanks for your answers